# Based on some biblatex style to realize bilingual output

Tags: biblatex, chinese

The image is what I want. I have try to fix the style based on gb7714-2015ms, which can allow user to use gb7714 style with Chinese bib, and default biblatex style with English. I almost realize the English style in the image, but it seems impossible to adjust with Chinese bib. Thus, I wonder if there is any resolution for bilingual output with different punctuation system.

The first image is in Word. The second image is the output result in LaTeX with MWE below.

[image: This is what I want in Word]

[image: This is the output result in LaTeX with MWE]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gb7714-2015ms,defernumbers=true,gbstyle=false,gbfieldtype=true,gbnamefmt=lowercase,gbnamefmt=givenahead,giveninits=false,doi=false,isbn=false,sorting=anyt,sortlocale=zh__pinyin]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{a.bib}
@book{hermanchomsky_2011,
    title = {制造共识:大众传媒的政治经济学},
    author = {爱德华·S·赫尔曼 and 诺姆·乔姆斯基},
    date = {2011-09},
    publisher = {{北京大学出版社}},
    location = {{北京}},
    langid = {中文;},
    translator = {邵红松}
  }
@article{hekai_2020,
    title = {中国崛起与国际秩序转型:一种类型化分析},
    author = {{贺凯} and {冯惠云}},
    date = {2020},
    journaltitle = {当代亚太},
    pages = {4--29},
    langid = {中文;},
    number = {3}
  }
@book{keohane_2012,
    title = {Power and {{Interdependence}}},
    author = {Keohane, Robert O. and Nye, Joseph S.},
    date = {2012},
    publisher = {{Longman}},
    location = {{Boston}},
    langid = {english}
  }
@article{nye_1996,
    title = {America's {{Information Edge}}},
    author = {Nye, Joseph S. and Owens, William A.},
    date = {1996},
    journaltitle = {Foreign Affairs},
    volume = {75},
    pages = {20--36},
    langid = {english},
    number = {2}
  }
@incollection{walker_2018,
    title = {Sharp {{Power}}},
    booktitle = {Sharp {{Power}}: {{Rising Authoritarian Influence}}},
    author = {Walker, Christopher and Ludwig, Jessica},
    editor = {Cardenal, Juan Pablo and Kucharczyk, Jacek and Mesežnikov, Grigorij and Pleschová, Gabriela},
    date = {2018},
    pages = {8--25},
    publisher = {{National Endowment for Democracy}},
    location = {{Washington, DC}},
    langid = {english}
  }
  @thesis{guoyouxin_2003,
  title = {穿越“铁幕”:美国对“苏东国家”的冷战宣传(1945--1963)},
  author = {{郭又新}},
  date = {2003},
  institution = {{东北师范大学}},
  location = {{长春}},
  annotation = {40 citations(CNKI)[2021-3-19]},
  langid = {中文;},
  type = {博士学位论文}
}
@thesis{pu_2012,
  title = {Limited {{Rebranding}}: {{Status Signaling}}, {{Multiple Audiences}}, and the {{Incoherence}} of {{China}}'s {{Grand Strategy}}},
  author = {Pu, Xiaoyu},
  date = {2012},
  institution = {{The Ohio State University}},
  location = {{Columbus, OH}},
  langid = {english},
  type = {Ph.D. Dissertation}
}
@incollection{skcopol_2009,
  title = {找回国家——当前研究的战略分析},
  booktitle = {找回国家},
  author = {{西达·斯考克波}},
  editor = {{彼得·埃文斯} and {迪特里希·鲁施迈耶} and {西达·斯考克波}},
  date = {2009-04},
  pages = {2--52},
  publisher = {{生活·读书·新知三联书店}},
  location = {{北京}},
  langid = {中文;},
  translator = {{方力维} and {莫宜瑞} and {黄琪轩}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{a.bib}  

\begin{document}

Some special Chinese punctuations and characters:

Comma ，

Period 。

Colon ：

Prefix and suffix of title, journal name and else 《》

Prefix and suffix of pages 第 页

"In" here in Chinese 载

After editor add 主编

After translator add 译

Dissertation in Chinese 学位论文

Year in Chinese like 2021年, if book, it can be 2021年版 or 2021年

Delimiter between authors 、 

\footfullcite[1-2]{hermanchomsky_2011}
\footfullcite{hekai_2020}
\footfullcite{skcopol_2009}
\footfullcite{guoyouxin_2003}
\footfullcite[1-2]{keohane_2012}
\footfullcite{nye_1996}
\footfullcite{walker_2018}
\footfullcite{pu_2012}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For Chinese specifically, I don't know. But, in general, at least for languages using a latin alphabet, you can add the `langid` field to have an automatic translation of the strings used by biblatex.

Comment: `biblatex` supports language switching and language-dependent definitions of certain macros. So in theory it should be possible to do something like this. If and how something like your screenshot is possible and details will depend on your document setup. I looked at [`biblatex-gb7714-2015`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gb7714-2015), but the documentation does not appear to be available in English and I have next to no experience typesetting Chinese, so if you could post a minimal example document of what you have so far I might be able to have a look at your issue.

Comment: @Bernard Many thanks, under GB7714, I just use langid to print the biblio with two languages.

Comment: @moewe Thank you. I add a MWE to question.

Comment: Is your document going to be in English, Chinese or both languages? (The MWE and the question make me think your document is going to be in English mainly, but I'd like to be sure.)

Comment: It would also help if you could add examples how you would normally typeset the Chinese punctuation you'd like to see in the context of your MWE. Do you use a special environment? Or just special characters?

Comment: @moewe I update the MWE and Word example to make comparison (with Chinese punctuation and characters). My document is written by Chinese, with some English instructions in body text, like author name and some proper noun. Thanks

Comment: It appears to me that `biblatex-gb7714-2015` does not use `biblatex`'s normal localisation features for localisation. Instead it has a very intricate system that works without language switching. But I'm afraid I don't fully understand how it works and from what I have seen so far I cannot think of a quick way to get what you want. Sorry.

Comment: @moewe Thanks again. It really has a very intricate system which actually will take more time to support my ideal style. Hope it can be solved one day, that's the meaning I post the question here, because it is helpful for many scholars in humanities and social science who use LaTeX.